# SQL Server Error:950

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an update for old project and the database is very old (SQL Server 2000). I'm trying to attach it to SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and it shows this message:

> cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server with error message code :950

Then I try to install SQL Server 2005 or 2000 but they're not compatible with  Windows 8.1.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess you have to use another machine (or a virtual machine) that you can install an older version of Windows and SQL Server on, or possibly try with SQL Sever 2008, but the original database probably needs to be from a SQL 2000 SP4 server.

Comment: Install SSMS 2008 *or* 2012. SSMS 2014 'does not support' SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @user2864740: SQL Server 2012 also doesn't directly support SQL Server 2000 .... you need 2008 or 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

you should have sp4 to install sql server 2000 because it is too old and is incompatible with 8.1 , 8  or 7 ..
you can't directly convert data from 2000 to 2014 or 2012 
first you have to take a pre step that is you have to convert it to 2008 and then convert to 2012 or 2014

**Note** to convert to 2008 from 2000 you should have sp4..